# Is it proper to use "it's" as an abbreviation for "it has"?

Tags: abbreviations, quotations

[A recent story in the New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/22/technology/uber-employees-react-travis-kalanick.html) quotes somebody as writing:

> I want the board to hear from Uber employees that **it’s [sic]** made the
> wrong decision ...

The [sic] here was in the original, and implies that the usage they're quoting is incorrect. However, *[it's](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/it%27s#English)* can be a contraction of both *it is* or *it has*, and expanding it out as the latter seems fine to me:

> I want the board to hear from Uber employees that **it has** made the
> wrong decision ...

Is the NYT being hypercorrect?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140575/discussion-on-question-by-lambshaanxy-is-it-proper-to-use-its-as-an-abbreviat).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *sic* does not appear in the article as currently posted by the *New York Times*. The sentence is grammatical as stands, that is, as quoted. Why a *sic* was there is beyond the ken of most educated people.