# Is this clause the passive or present perfect?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is this clause 'it's met with utter confusion' the passive or present perfect?

> Have you ever talked with a friend about a problem, only to realize
>   that they just don’t seem to grasp why the issue is so important to
>   you? Have you ever presented an idea to a group, and **it’s met with
>   utter confusion**? Or maybe you’ve been in an argument when the other
>   person suddenly accuses you of not listening to what they’re saying at
>   all? What’s going on here?

http://blog.ed.ted.com/2016/03/31/how-to-avoid-miscommunication-in-ted-ed-gifs/

Comment: That depends on whether _it's_ means _it has_ or _it is_. This is a good example of a situation where contraction is not helpful.

Comment: Hello, Lifeispicnic (are you serious?) The << it's >> used here may be the 'it is' or the 'it has' contraction. [This has been covered here before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395254/is-it-proper-to-use-its-as-an-abbreviation-for-it-has). ////  'It has met with ...' is the present perfect and 'It is met with' is the present passive construction (used dramatically for a past event). //// Which is intended here? Probably the passive, reasoning from parallelism. But the phrasing is certainly ambiguous. //// I'm working on whether or not this is more suitable as an ELL question.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have: "it’s met with utter confusion?"

So, let's get to it. Passive voice means the subject was acted upon. So, "**it** was met" means "**it**" was acted upon. That's passive voice. For active voice, it'd be "**it** met with utter confusion". Present perfect means that a thing started in the past but has current results. The previous poster was right. To use present perfect tense, you'd have to be clear, such as: "it has met (instead of it's) with utter confusion." Otherwise, that sentence could be read as "It is with utter confusion". Or, you could use past perfect: "it had met with utter confusion."